# Upgrade Angular 5 - issue with prod build

Tags: angular

We have used **sessionStorage.getItem** in one of the component.

previously, we were using Angular 4 and with that if i run

```
ng build --prod
```

then in my main.bundle file, i am seeing sessionStorage.getItem(**) and its working correctly in prod build.

But after upgrading to Angular 5, if i make build for prod then in main.bundle.js i am seeing o._storage.getItem(**).

After upgrade our prod build is not running at all. Its throwing below error.

```
"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.
at Function.QnL0.n.getItem(main.bundle.js)"
```

We are not able to find exact what is issue. Here we are just guessing regarding this part. Sorry this might be very less details.

TIA

Comment: with the provided code is impossible to know whats wrong

Comment: i had put less data, because i am not sure exactly what is the issue. i just tried to guess after comparing two (one of ng4 with ng5) prod bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

If this is your error (because it could not be it, with the little informatino you provided), just do

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem(**)
```

this will tell the compiler to use the window object, that remains untouched during build.

Answer (score 0):

There was inner dependency which required **ngx-store** package. But I dont know why it didnt gave any error while --prod build or in local. With adding that package now its working correct.